# Using preparedStatement to prevent SQL injection

Tags: prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am having an SQL query like this:

```
StringBuilder sSelect = new StringBuilder("SELECT C ");
StringBuilder sFrom = new StringBuilder(" FROM CUSTOMER as C ");

if (phoneNumber != null)
{
  sFrom.append(" where C.number = ").append(phoneNumber);
}
```

I would like a solution to prevent SQL injection. Something like this works fine:

```
sWhere.append(" I.indicNom=").append(":sPhoneNumber").append(" ");
parameters.put("sPhoneNumber", phoneNumber);
```

My purpose is to use preparedStatement. Is it possible to create SQL progressively?

For example:

```
select * from tableX if(condition) {add where X=:Y } else {do nothing}
```

instead of

```
select * from tableX where X=?
```

Comment: What SQL engine are you using, it will be relevant to the answers.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I'm using persistence jdbc

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic means for discovering and preventing all classes of SQL injection attack *a priori*.